# php - remove xml element but keep children

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have this xml-structure

```
<root>
    <child id="1">
        <child id="2" />
    <child id="3" />
    <child id="4">
      <child id="5" />
    </child>
    <child id="6" />
  </child>
</root>
```

Now i need to strip "child id=1" but keep its children as children from root, like this:

```
<root>
  <child id="2" />
  <child id="3" />
  <child id="4">
    <child id="5" />
  </child>
  <child id="6" />
</root>
```

I've tried importing / cloning element but don't get the result i want.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleXML extension.
You can iterate the XML then check the node you want to remove for example : 
if(child[id] = 1) 
  removeChild($objXML);